# Python Django equivelant of preloading in Elixir Ecto

Tags: python, django, orm, elixir, ecto

So I am coming from Elixir and Phoenix Background now working in a Django project.

At this stage I am investigating the ORM part of Django and I have the following question

Assume a model like the following

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
```

At this point in Ecto you can do something like the following

```
shop = Context.get_by_id(1)
shop = preload(shop, :products)
```

and the result would be

```
%Shop{
 name: "Some name",
 products: [
   %Product{},
   %Product{}
 ] 
}
```

Taking care of all the necceesary joing queries behind the scene is there any similar functionality when working with Django ?

Comment: Of cause, and that is why it is explained in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/).

Comment: Oh I got started with a book, my bad thanks for the lead though !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it with [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in [`querysets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/)

In your case you can do:

```
shop = Shop.objects.select_related('products').get(id=5)
```

or

```
shops = Shop.objects.prefetch_related('products').all()
```

There is a difference between `select_related` and `prefetch_related` on when it performs the query in the docs.